# Программно задать размер FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Нужно программно задать размер `FrameLayout` , ширина 50 px, высота 70px, пробовал так, но приложения падает:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayput.LayoutParams(50,70);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) приложение падает всегда со стактрейсом ошибки. Очень, очень, очень плохо просить помощи не прилагая к решению проблемы никаких усилий. Если проблема в ошибке, никто не станет угадывать, что за ошибка возникла.
2) Да, я все же угадаю. сам `FrameLayout` лежит не во `FrameLayout`'e, правильно? Вот в зависимости от того, в чем он лежит, и нужно передавать определенный тип `LayoutParams` в `setLayoutParams`. Так, если он лежит в `LinearLayout`, то вызывать нужно так:
`frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,70));`
для `RelativeLayout`:
`frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50,70));`